# WPF Caliburn.Micro uses wrong platform provider

Tags: caliburn.micro

In my ShellViewModel PlatformProvider.Current results in a XamlPlatformProvider as expected. In another ViewModel navigated to in a Frame PlatformProvider.Current results in a DefaultPlatformProvider.
Furthermore if I trigger a function in the ShellViewModel I can see that PlatformProvider.Current still results in a XamlPlatformProvider, so that ViewModel isn't affected.

This results in errors on Caliburn.Micro.Execute.OnUIThread and other platform specific calls such as using a BindableCollection.
It started happening after updating a large project to Caliburn.Micro version 4.0.173 from version 3.2.0.

I've been unable to reproduce the error in a smaller test project, so I can not show meaningful code.
I've tried replacing the whole bootstrapper with a minimal one and still see the error.

**EDIT:**
Creating a UI component from code within Caliburn.Micro.Execute.BeginOnUIThread gives the error:
"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this".
Altering a BindableCollection gives the error:
"This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."

The above scenarios work if I wrap them in a Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke which indicates that Caliburn.Micro fails to use the Dispatcher/UI thread.

I'm using C# on .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  What version of .net framework, .net core, or .net are you using?

Comment: @KenTucker I've appended the information to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second ViewModel, which was throwing errors was in a second project that included the NuGet package Caliburn.Micro.Core instead of Caliburn.Micro. Updating both to the same version solved the issue.
I had used NuGets Consolidate function to update Caliburn.Micro in the whole solution and had missed Caliburn.Micro.Core.